# Does anyone know how to create a sharepoint search alert using c#?

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, alert

i need to develop some sharepoint search alert related werb part and would be grateful if anyone who has previous knowlenge in this area share code snippets or sights where i am guided.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code for creating alerts: 
[User's Alerts always null](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47608/users-alerts-always-null)

I would then go check out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spalert_members.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spalerttemplate_members.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897791.aspx

With the MS structure in mind you should be able to create some example alerts in the gui then fish out their properties with powershell:

```
    PS H:\> $w = get-spweb http://mysites.NotReally.com
    PS H:\> $w = get-spweb http://mysites.NotReally.com/sites/ghangas
    PS H:\> $w.alerts | ? {$_.AlertTemplateName -like "oss*"}


    Title             : Search: tasks
    AlertTemplateName : OSS.Search
    AlertTemplate     : SPAlertTemplate Name=OSS.Search
    Filter            :
    Properties        : {p_query, eventtypeindex, p_lastnotificationtime, filterindex...}
    ID                : 7d49e2a8-0164-4880-9bd1-84a726558c5f
    ListID            :
    MatchId           : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    ItemID            :
    ListUrl           :
    List              :
    Item              :
    AlwaysNotify      : True
    DeliveryChannels  : Email
    AlertType         : Custom
    EventType         : Add
    EventTypeBitmask  : 1
    AlertFrequency    : Daily
    AlertTime         : 10/19/2012 11:00:00 AM
    Status            : On
    User              : ghangas
    UserId            : 1
    DynamicRecipient  :

    PS H:\> ($w.alerts | ? {$_.AlertTemplateName -like "oss*"}).properties["p_query"]
    <Query Culture="en-US" EnableStemming="False" EnablePhonetic="False" EnableNicknames="False" IgnoreAllNoiseQuery="True" 
    SummaryLength="185" KeywordInclusion="0" QueryText="tasks" TrimDuplicates="True" Site="f5618d6c-4613-4e94-ad8f-e9c0dfae2a80"
    KeywordType="True" HiddenConstraints=" site:&quot;http://mysites.NotReally.com/sites/ghangas/Lists/Tasks&quot; " />
```

With this as a starting point you should be able to see what you can play with, where to build a query, and how to work with the MS Alert structure.