# Modifying the contents/template of the sharepoint Search alert mail?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, alert, search-api

I'm doing some RND on SharePoint search alert! I'm looking on how to modify the SharePoint search alerts mail. as in the Daily Alert Summary. Is there anyone who knows to do this? Please note I'm talking about "SharePoint Search Alert"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh161512(v=office.14).aspx#bkAlertTemplates

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered before here:

[Does anyone know how to create a sharepoint search alert using c#?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49094/does-anyone-know-how-to-create-a-sharepoint-search-alert-using-c/49517#49517)

Also here:
[How to create custom email alert template in SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13216/how-to-create-custom-email-alert-template-in-sharepoint-2010)